# How to map points in a 3D-plane into screen plane

Tags: graphics

I have given an assignment of to project a object in 3D space into a 2D plane using simple graphics in C. The question is that a cube is placed in fixed 3D space and there is camera which is placed in a position whose co-ordinates are x,y,z and the camera is looking at the origin i.e. 0,0,0. Now we have to project the cube vertex into the camera plane.

I am proceeding with the following steps

Step 1: I find the equation of the plane aX+bY+cZ+d=0 which is perpendicular to the line drawn from the camera position to the origin.

Step 2: I find the projection of each vertex of the cube to the plane which is obtained in the above step.

Now I want to map those vertex position which i got by projection in step 2 in the plane aX+bY+cZ+d=0 into my screen plane.

thanks,

I don't think that by letting the z co-ordinate equals zero will lead me to the actual mapping. So any help to figure out this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in two simple steps:

1. Translate the cube's coordinates to the camera's system (using
   rotation), such that the camera's own coordinates in that system are x=y=z=0 and the cube's translated z's are > 0.
2. Project the translated cube's coordinates onto a 2d plain by dividing its x's and y's by their respective z's (you may need to apply a constant scaling factor here for the coordinates to be reasonable for the screen, e.g. not too small and within +/-half the screen's height in pixels). This will create the perspective effect. You can now draw pixels using these divided x's and y's on the screen assuming x=y=0 is the center of it.

This is pretty much how it is done in 3d games. If you use cube vertex coordinates, then you get projections of its sides onto the screen. You may then solid-fill the resultant 2d shapes or texture-map them. But for that you'll have to first figure out which sides are not obscured by others (unless, of course, you use a technique called z-buffering). You don't need that for a simple wire-frame demo, though, just draw straight lines between the projected vertices.